# How many different ways could I fill a table with 20 different items to selected from 30 items?

Tags: combinations

How can I create unique tables of 20 contents each with each unique table generating its contents from a list of 30 items?

I have a list of items 1 to 30. I want to generate a table that contains 20 unique items picked from my 30 lists. No contents of a group should be similar. Each table is unique in terms of the 20 contents within it.

How many tables can this be created and is there a tool (or excel) to help me generate this?

Comment: Do you wish to create an ordered list.  For instance, is red, blue, green considered different from blue, green, red?

Comment: Are their duplicate items ? This would change the answer.